# How to create a subquery in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I am so confused with how to properly do a Microsoft Access subquery.  I have an assingment in which I'm supposed to create one, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  Here is the problem:

Q3. Obtain the Last and First Names of all second authors whose books were ordered. Print these names next to their book titles. Show also the total amount sold of each of these titles. The total amount sold is the quantity of books in a orderline multiplied by their price and added for all orders of the same author. Order the results in descending order of the total amount sold (Hint: Use the SUM function to add the multiplications and GROUP BY to make these additions per author and title).

I've figured out the SQL for both parts (or so I think).  Here is what I've got so far:

Prints the Title, Last Name, and First Name:

```
SELECT Book.Title, Author.LastName, Author.FirstName<br>
FROM Wrote, Author, Book, OrderLine<br>
WHERE Wrote.AuthorRank = 2<br>
AND Wrote.AuthorId = Author.AuthorID<br>
AND Book.ISBN = Wrote.ISBN<br>
AND OrderLine.ISBN = Book.ISBN;
```

To calculate the total amount sold:

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity * Price) AS TotalAmountSold<br>
FROM Book, OrderLine<br>
GROUP BY Title;
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to put these together to achieve what the question is asking of me.  Any tips to help me understand how to do something like this?  Thanks in advance.

[image: Author Table]
[image: Book Table]
[image: Customer Table]
[image: Order Table]
[image: OrderLine Table Part 1]
[image: OrderLine Table Part 2]
[image: Wrote Table]

Comment: Your aggregate query won't give correct calcs because there is no JOIN clause. Build a nested query by copy/paste one SQL statement into another in SQLView. So build a query that joins queries/tables then copy/paste so end up with something like `SELECT q1.*, q2.* FROM q1 INNER JOIN (SELECT …) AS q2 ON q1.ISBN=q2.ISBN ORDER BY TotalAmountSold DESC;`. Use JOIN clause whenever possible instead of WHERE to link tables. What is 'second' author?

Comment: I believe what he meant by second author is on the Wrote table, if the AuthorRank field = 2.  They would be attributed to being the second author of the book.

Answer (score 0):

Build and save Query 1:

```
SELECT OrderLine.ISBN, Title, Sum([Quantity]*[Price]) AS TotalAmountSold
FROM OrderLine INNER JOIN Book ON OrderLine.ISBN = Book.ISBN
GROUP BY OrderLine.ISBN, Title;
```

Build query 2:

```
SELECT Author.AuthorID, FirstName, LastName, Title, TotalAmountSold
FROM (Author INNER JOIN Wrote ON Author.AuthorID = Wrote.AuthorID) 
INNER JOIN Query1 ON Wrote.ISBN = Query1.ISBN
WHERE (((Wrote.AuthorRank)=2))
ORDER BY TotalAmountSold DESC;
```

If you want an all-in-one SQL, copy/paste Query1 SQL into Query2 so the result is like:

```
SELECT Author.AuthorID, FirstName, LastName, Title, TotalAmountSold
FROM (Author INNER JOIN Wrote ON Author.AuthorID = Wrote.AuthorID) 
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT OrderLine.ISBN, Title, Sum([Quantity]*[Price]) AS TotalAmountSold
      FROM OrderLine INNER JOIN Book ON OrderLine.ISBN = Book.ISBN
      GROUP BY OrderLine.ISBN, Title) AS Query1 
ON Wrote.ISBN = Query1.ISBN
WHERE (((Wrote.AuthorRank)=2))
ORDER BY TotalAmountSold DESC;
```

Save Query2 and delete Query1.

Comment: Thank you for this.  We haven't even gotten into how to use JOIN yet.  From what I've gathered thus far, I've now learned that GROUP BY should only be used for aggregate functions.  This helped me to learn how to use these correctly.  The only trouble I am having now is how to use ORDER BY with my Query.  Here is what I have:

Comment: SELECT Book.Title, Author.LastName, Author.FirstName,  SUM(Quantity * Price) AS [Total Amount Sold]
FROM Wrote, Author, Book, OrderLine
WHERE Wrote.AuthorRank = 2
AND Wrote.AuthorId = Author.AuthorID
AND Book.ISBN = Wrote.ISBN
AND OrderLine.ISBN = Book.ISBN
GROUP BY Title, LastName, FirstName;

Comment: The last thing I need to figure out is how to order the results in descending order by the total amount sold which was created in the aggregate function of SUM.

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is starting to make sense now.